# Proving a function g: R^2 → {(x,y):x^2+y^2 ≤ 1} is injective. (function given in comments).

Tags: functions, relations

This is the function I am trying to prove is injective:
$$g(x,y)=\Bigg(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}\Bigg).$$

I am proving it is injective by proving the contrapositive. Starting as so:
$$g(x_1,y_1)=g(x_2,y_2)$$
$$\Bigg(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}+1},\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}+1}\Bigg)=\Bigg(\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}+1},\frac{y_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}+1}\Bigg)$$

I thought about trying to set each component of the ordered pair equal to each other like:
$$\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}+1}=\frac{x_2}{\sqrt{x_2^2+y_2^2}+1}$$
And likewise for the second component. But I do not know where to start when it comes to the actual algebra (other than, it kind of is just obvious(?)) but yeah... any help to actually rigorously prove this is appreciated!

The original question where this function originated is: Consider the subset $B=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\vert B\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}^2\vert$. And using the Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem I found and proved an injective function from $B$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. This function was given by my textbook to prove, I would have no idea how to find such a function, and now I'm stuck proving it with no idea where to go forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g(x,y)=g(z,t)$, then $\|g(x,y)\|=\|g(z,t)\|$; in other words,$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}=\frac{\sqrt{z^2+t^2}}{\sqrt{z^2+t^2}+1}.$$But$$\frac a{a+1}=\frac b{b+1}\iff1-\frac1{a+1}=1-\frac1{1+b}\iff a=b.$$So, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{z^2+t^2}$, and therefore\begin{multline}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1},\frac y{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}\right)=\left(\frac z{\sqrt{z^2+t^2}+1},\frac t{\sqrt{z^2+t^2}+1}\right)\implies\\\implies(x,y)=(z,t).\end{multline}

Answer (score 3):

Seeing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$ via $(x,y) \simeq x+iy$, the function $g$ is just the function $g : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$g(z)= \frac{z}{|z|+1}$$

Let's prove that $g$ is injective : let $z$ and $z'$ such that $g(z)=g(z')$. Then
$$\frac{z}{|z|+1} = \frac{z'}{|z'|+1} \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$$

so
$$\frac{|z|}{|z|+1} = \frac{|z'|}{|z'|+1}$$

so $|z|=|z'|$ because the function $t \mapsto \displaystyle{\frac{t}{t+1}}$ is injective. From $(1)$, you get directly that $z=z'$ and you are done.